# Android Notification Sound is not Playing completely on Bulk Notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to use android `Notifications` in my app. My app is push notification based and it shows popup notification with notification sound. 
I am facing problem while generating notification on every new event. For single notification every thing works fine but when I send `bulk messages` to app then `notification sound` is not playing completely and it get mixed with next notification sound.
I have written `generateNotification` function. Can any one guide me how can I achieve that notification sound should play only when previous sound is completed?

Below is my function:

```
private void generateNotification(Context aContext,JSONObject aJsonObject) throws JSONException {
        DAOFactory mySQLLiteDaoFactory;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = null;
        try {
            mySQLLiteDaoFactory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(DAOFactory.SQLITE);
            mySQLLiteDaoFactory.setContext(aContext);
            IAlertDAO myAlertDao = mySQLLiteDaoFactory.getAlertDAO();
            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(aContext.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(aContext).setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setNumber(myAlertDao.getUnreadMessageCount()+1)
                    .setContentTitle(aJsonObject.getJSONObject("Alert").get("AlertTitle").toString())
                    .setContentText("Severity: " + aJsonObject.getJSONObject("Alert").get("Severity").toString() + ", Type: " + aJsonObject.getJSONObject("Alert").get("AlertType").toString())
                    .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_ALERTS).setGroupSummary(true);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            mBuilder.setSound(uri);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(aContext, LoginActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(aContext);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoginActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) aContext.getSystemService(aContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Any help would be great favor.